# How can I forward a port from one docker container to another?

Tags: docker, portforwarding, docker-network

I commonly see solutions that expose a docker container's port to the host.

In my case **I want to forward a local port** from one container, to another.

Let's say I run a service on **container A** that has a **hard-coded configuration to access db on localhost 3306**. But I want to run the db server on **container B**.

What is the best way to port-forward **from A-localhost:3306 to B-IP:3306**?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Install `socat` in your container and at startup run

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:3306,fork TCP:B-IP:3306 &
```

This will listen locally on your 3306 and pass any traffic bidirectionally to `B-IP:3306`. socat is available in package named socat. So you will run any of the below commands to install it

```
$ yum install -y socat
$ apt install -y socat
$ apk add socat
```

**Edit-1**

You can even do this by not touching your original container

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add socat
```

Build the file as below

```
docker build -t socat .
```

Now run a container from same

```
docker run --name mysql-bridge-a-to-b --net=container:<containerAid> socat socat TCP-LISTEN:3306,fork TCP:BIP:3306
```

This will run this container on A's network. So when it listens on A's network the `localhost:3306` will become available in A even though A container was not touched.

Comment: There is an Alpine socat image on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat/

Comment: Even though my issue was not related directly to this, this helped me solve it.! Thanks and cheers :)

Comment: `--net=container:someContainer`. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: This works well for a single container, however, how should I do this for multi containers, say, mapping `A:3306 -> B:3306` and `C:3306 -> B:3306`, should I start 2 `socat` containers?

Comment: You can use nginx with a stream forwarding as well, or multiple socats if needed

Comment: Using alpine/socat: `docker run --network=container:nameOrIdOfcontainerA alpine/socat TCP-LISTEN:3306,fork TCP:nameOrIpOfContainerB:3306`
And documentation for [--network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-container)

Comment: Thank you! This works in docker compose too (sorry for the bad formatting, SO doesn't seem to support multiline comments) `socat:      image: alpine/socat        network_mode: service:container-a          depends_on:           - container-a       command: "TCP-LISTEN:9090,fork,reuseaddr TCP:container-b:9090"`

Answer (score 26):

If you want container B's port to be exposed as a localhost port on container A you can start container B with the `network` option set to `container` mode to start container B on container A's network namespace.

Example:

```
docker run --net=container:A postgres
```

Where:

- `A` is the name or identifier of the container you want to map into.

This will startup postgres in a container on the same network namespace as `A`, so any port opened in the postgres container will be being opened on the same interface as `A` and it should be available on `localhost` inside container A.

Comment: This seems to me more appropriate than `docker run --network=host`

Comment: docker compose version please?

Comment: @PawelCioch: I think that it should be `network_mode: "service:A"
` inside the service definition of `postgres` container. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode

Answer (score 24):

You can simply run the container with network mode equal to host.

```
docker run --network=host ...
```

In that case, from the container point of view, localhost or 127.0.0.1 will refer to the host machine. Thus if your db is running in another container B that listens on 3306, an address of localhost:3306 in container A will hit the database in container B.

Comment: this actually solved me. dockerA runs in its own network (and maybe exposed to host). dockerB is the same. my intuition was that when exposing it on `docker run -p` that will transparently make it has the host network

Comment: this is only supported on Linux: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: Why not use a bridge/overlay network?

Comment: This might lead to port conflicts, either with the host or with containers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939762/6419007 seems to be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Containers can access each other on a shared network. You dont need to expose or forward anything.

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

Comment: Only true if they share the same file. Otherwise they act as two separate containers with no access to each other and you need a portmapping.

Comment: @DavidS You seem to imply using Compose, which is not a requirement. You can do `docker run --network` and two images can use each other's names

Answer (score -1):

This solution is way overkill for the use case stated but in the case you run across this while researching a larger scope.

Hashicorp Consul installs a localhost agent that will proxy the localhost port to the ipaddress and port of a service registered within the directory.
https://www.consul.io/intro

I have no relation to Hashicorp besides using their products in systems I've built.

Comment: Overkill. Bridge networks are builtin https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file).

docker-compose.yml example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .web
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql:3306  # the service name below
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
  mysql:
    build: .mysql
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"  # optional: used for accessing from the host, not from the other container
```

Here you have 2 docker instances: web and mysql, so each docker instance can see each other using the names you defined as services.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted without a comment. This works best for me since I don't have to mess with figuring out the port or hostname of the other container. The URI for mysql would be <service-name:port> e.g. "mysql:3306"

Comment: @Stevko because the db access is hardcoded to `localhost:3306`. It is not possible to change it to link to `mysql:3306`.