# Docker compose mapping port from container to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mapping, port

I am trying to map the port of the db-container to my containers localhost:port. Is there a way to map these ports? (I want to reach the db inside wildfly on localhost at port 12345)

currently, my db is only under oracle:1521 reachable. but I want it to be reachable under localhost:12345.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  wildfly:
    image: wildfly:latest
    ports:
    - "32004:32004"
    depends_on:
    - oracle
    links:
    - oracle
  oracle:
    image: oracle-db:latest
    expose:
    - "1521"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:1521"]
      interval: 2m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Sure, map exposed container port 1521 to host port 12345 with

```
ports:
    - "12345:1521"
```

for your oracle service like you do in the wildfly service. The pattern is `HOST_PORT:EXPOSED_CONTAINER_PORT`.

Comment: if i add the port (1234:1521) to my wildfly, i cannot reach the oracle-db under localhost. the port is not reachable from wildfly

Comment: You don't have to add anything to wildfly. If you want to map port 1521 from your oracle service to your host port 12345 you just have to replace `expose:
    - "1521"` in the oracle service with `ports:
    - "12345:1521"`. You don't have to change anything regarding your wildfly service.

Comment: i probably describe my issue wrong. i want to reach the db inside of wildfly on localhost:12345. not on my host.

Comment: Oh, I see..sorry for the misunderstanding. I have no solution for that on impulse. May I ask why you want to be able to reach it from localhost:1521 instead of oracle:1521 from within wildfly container?

Comment: because I don't want to change any of the application code. I only want to bring the current application into docker.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099874/how-can-i-forward-a-port-from-one-docker-container-to-another. It seems like it is exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As far as the wildfly container is concerned, `localhost` is the wildfly container.  You’d connect to the database as with an `oracle` host name (the name of the service in the `docker-compose.yml`).