# How can I forward a port from one container to another in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker-compose, portforwarding

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939762/2158271) for forwarding a port from one Docker container to another. How can I do the same in Docker Compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to define using `network_mode` key ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode)):

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  foo:
    container_name: foo

  bar:
    network_mode: container:foo
```

Though I'd rather avoid that; this isn't 'port forwarding', this is an instruction to use network stack of another container. Better use service names instead of `localhost`. I.e. to address `foo` container port use `foo:<port>` instead of `localhost:<port>`. This way you won't be limited in replicas and network configuration options.

Comment: I usually use service names but in this case the application has `localhost` hard coded as database hostname and I must somehow get `localhost:5432` forwarded to `dbcontainer:5432`.